Error when retrieving large integer value from Active Directory in Excel [VBA]
I am working on a VBA script within Excel to retrieve the expiration time of a LAPS (Local Administrator Password Solution) password from Active Directory. The expiration time is stored as a large integer value in the "ms-Mcs-AdmPwdExpirationTime" attribute.
AD Attribute
I have no problem getting string attribute value such as OperatingSystem attribute.
error occurs when i use attribute with "Large Integer" values.
Error 438 in line
GetLapsPasswordExpiration = adoRecordset.Fields(expirationTimeAttribute).Value
Option Explicit

Public Function GetLapsPasswordExpiration(ByVal computerName As String) As String
Dim adoCommand As Object
Dim adoConnection As Object
Dim adoRecordset As Object
Dim searchBase As String
Dim filter As String
Dim expirationTimeAttribute As String ' Attribute for expiration time

' Set the search base to the domain root
searchBase = "<LDAP://" & GetDomainRoot() & ">"

' Set the filter to search for the computer object
filter = "(&(objectClass=computer)(cn=" & computerName & "))"

' Set the expiration time attribute
expirationTimeAttribute = "usnchanged"

' Create the ADO objects
Set adoCommand = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
Set adoConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set adoRecordset = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

' Configure the ADO objects
adoConnection.Provider = "ADsDSOObject"
adoConnection.Open "Active Directory Provider"
adoCommand.ActiveConnection = adoConnection
adoCommand.CommandText = searchBase & ";" & filter & ";" & expirationTimeAttribute & ";subtree"
adoCommand.Properties("Page Size") = 1000
adoCommand.Properties("Timeout") = 30
adoCommand.Properties("Searchscope") = 2

' Execute the ADO query
Set adoRecordset = adoCommand.Execute

' Return the expiration time if it exists
If Not adoRecordset.EOF Then
    GetLapsPasswordExpiration = adoRecordset.Fields(expirationTimeAttribute).Value
Else
    GetLapsPasswordExpiration = "Computer not found or LAPS password not set."
End If

I expect to retrieve the large integer value. However, I'm stuck with the error and unsure how to proceed. Any insights or alternative approaches to handle large integer values from Active Directory in VBA would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Have a look to the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59381108/how-to-manage-in-vba-date-objects-retrieved-from-adsdsoobject-provider

"I'm stuck with the error" - always helps to be specific about what exact error you're seeing, and on which line.

Got error in line GetLapsPasswordExpiration = adoRecordset.Fields(expirationTimeAttribute).Value
